# impulse response function in r

Tags: r, var

I have a doubt about some arguments in **irf** function in R. Among its arguments, there are *cumulative = TRUE (or FALSE)* and *ortho = TRUE (or FALSE)*. 
I read the documentation but I still don't get it. In the documentation says  *"ortho = if TRUE (the default) the orthogonalised impulse response coefficients are computed (only for objects of class ‘varest’).*

So, the question is: What's the difference between orthogonalised impulse response coefficients and cumulated impulse response coefficients?

Comment: The irf function does not belong to r. You should mention what package you're using and add its tag (if it has one).

Comment: Cumulated impulse response coefficients are useful when you are interested in the response of the levels of Yt rather than their first differences. This is not an R programming question.

Comment: Sorry... I'm using the package vars.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366766/direction-of-orthogonalization-in-the-vars-package-in-r Regarding the orthogonalization used in the VARS package.

Answer (score 3):

The vars package for R has functionality for impulse response function. In particular, see the irf() command. For an example on usage, see my code here:

https://gist.github.com/jpicerno1/97a6df866488c069aa5a

along with the accompanying blog post:

http://www.capitalspectator.com/modeling-what-if-scenarios-with-impulse-response-simulations/

Answer (score 2):

regarding the orthogonalised impulse response coefficients it seems that is the indentification strategy. You use a certain ordering of variables so that the shocks to specific variables are ortogonal to other variables. Check the Cholesky decomposition for example, which is the most popular used ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)). Regarding the cumulative IRF, you are just adding the effects, so it accumulates. They will never will go back to the steady state but reach a negative or positive value, depending on the effects.